Light-hearted English show, featuring a detective whose wife mysteriously disappeared
The central protagonist is a private investigator with a teenage daughter, and a missing wife. He has one male, and two female staff, one of whom he vaguely flirts with, but he seems haunted by his missing wife. The team work out of a small, (possibly mobile or temporary building?) office. I only remember him playing golf with a rich person while investigating a murder.
The show is most likely from between 2005 and 2012, and I think set in a smallish English city or town. There were no sci-fi elements. The leading man has dark eyes and dark, slightly thinning hair, and enjoys making pedantic language jokes that others do not enjoy. Not to be confused with the show Case Histories.

Do you remember the cases they investigated? Was there a sci-fi element?

No sci-fi @Walt. I only remember him playing golf with a rich person while investigating a murder.

Are you sure it was a PI because it sounds a bit like a show about a small town lawyer - Kingdom - with Stephen Fry.  The two female employees fit

I now recall, the show is called The Gil Mayo Mysteries. BBC (2006). Only 1 series made unfortunately. Here is a review from The (Melbourne) Age  http://www.theage.com.au/news/tv-reviews/the-gil-mayo-mysteries/2008/06/11/1212863721560.html

Slightly vague, but it sounds like it could be Case Histories:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01sfp1n
The lead is a PI who fits your physical description, he has a teenage daughter, the series ran from 2011-13 and is set in Edinburgh.  He also has a female assistant who flirts with him.  To be honest I've not seen it, but I found that by some judicious Googling and it seems to fit pretty well.

I've fleshed it out a bit.  Since I've not seen it I would have added the suggestion as a comment, but I don't yet have the reputation...

Not Case Histories, thanks for the suggestion.
